# How to work with singular gauge transformations in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, topology

I was recently considering a problem analogous to the Aharonov-Bohm (AB) effect but in the context of quantum field theory. Consider then Dirac electrons minimally coupled to an AB flux and described by the (Euclidean) Lagrangian density

$L= \bar{\psi} \,  \gamma^{\mu}(\partial_{\mu}+i \, \phi \, \partial_{\mu}\eta)\psi  $

Here $\bar{\psi}$ and $\psi$ are fermionic (grassmanian) fields, $\phi$ is the strength of the flux and $\eta$ is a scalar field. As in the standard AB case, it seems that I can gauge $\eta$ away. However, since $\eta$ contains the flux, it is not a smooth field and the gauge transformation will be "singular". I would then expect to obtain some extra contribution from the path integral measure over non homotopic field configurations. Does anybody know how to treat this problem? I have found a great deal about quantum mechanical path integrals over non simply connected spaces in the literature, but nothing about the QFT extension. Any suggestion, references etc is welcome!!!

Comment: I suggest you put in more equations in here.

Comment: Have you heard of *instantons*? Since your "AB theory" is the special case of a U(1) gauge theory where the gauge field is (for what *reason* I'm unsure) pure gauge, that is exactly what we're dealing with. Answering this question would require a complete introduction into gauge theory for someone unfamiliar with it, so I'm voting to close as *too broad*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I am familiar with instantons in quantum mechanics. Here the problem is related but not exactly the same since this is not the classic example of the instanton in the non-abelian gauge theory. Actually, the problem is closely related to the Fujikawa's treatment of anomalies. Can you at least give me a good reference on the connection between path integral measure and instantons?